# Replace boolean with an image in a ASPXGridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, boolean, aspxgridview

I have a few columns on my ASPXGridView which contain boolean values.

I want to replace the the values that are 'True' with a tick icon.
Then I want to replace the values which are false with a cross icon.

Is there a way of doing this? I already have the icon images for the tick and cross.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

ASPX:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Image ID="imgBooleanState" runat="server" AlternateText="State" ImageUrl='<%# GetBooleanState(Eval("MyBooleanValue")) %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Code behind:

```
protected string GetBooleanState(object state)
{
    bool result = false;
    Boolean.TryParse(state.ToString(), out result);
    if (result)
    {
         return ResolveUrl("~/path/tick.png");
    }
    else
    {
         return ResolveUrl("~/path/cross.png");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check boolean value on rowdatabound and accordingly bind the image as follows:

```
protected void gridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    Image imgCtrl = (Image) e.Row.FindControl("imgCtrl");
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        If(e.Row.DataItem("BooleanField"))
        {
        imgCtrl.ImageUrl = TickImagePath;
        }
        else
        {
        imgCtrl.ImageUrl = CrossImagePath;  
        } 
    }
}
```

In above code i have simply checked the value of your `boolean` field on `rowdatabound` and accordingly seted the `image path` or decided whether to set "Cross Image path" or set "Tick image" path.